# Show that heat flux is also a solution to the Heat Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

We're given that if the temperature $u(t,x)$ of a homogeneous bar satisfies the heat equation, we're to show that the associated heat flux $w(t,x)$ is another solution to the same equation.

I know that $$w(t,x) =-\kappa(x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$
and the solution for the heat equation is given by
$$u(t,x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n  \exp\left[-\frac{\gamma\ n^2\pi^2t} {l^2}  \right] \sin(\frac{ n\pi x}{l})$$

My question is where do I begin with this problem? Do I just start like I would with solving the original heat equation and applying separation of variables to $w(t,x)$ like
$$w(t,x) = T(t)X(x)$$
and proceeding from there? Or do I start at the solution of the heat equation and plug stuff in until things work out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out it's actually way easier than either of those two suggestions. We can treat the thermal conductivity variable $\kappa(x)$ as a constant, so that we have the heat flux given by $$w(t,x) =-\kappa\frac{\partial u}{\partial x},$$

we first take the derivative of the heat equation with respect to $x$:
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial t} = -\kappa\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^3}$$

Then changing the order of partial derivatives and substituting gives us
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\left(-\kappa\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right) = \left(-\kappa\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)  \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$

Which is just
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}w(t,x) = w(t,x) \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$